# bootstrap 'affix' on navbar breaks the right margin

Tags: css, html, navbar, affix

Hi guys I'm learning bootstrap by doing a personal webpage. I've created a navbar with the affix option but when scrolling down the right margin seems broken. Can You help me to figure out why? 
Thanks in advance, here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable fade in">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <strong>Warning!</strong> This site uses cookies
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Something</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Pag 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Pag 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: Using chrome inspector i've found a warning. It says :"The key "width:device-width" is not recognized and ignored."

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some closing tags. I hope the below snippet helps you out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Something</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pag 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pag 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"/></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! this works for me but I'm trying to find a way to omit the "navbar-fixed-top" class in the navbar declaration becouse I don't like too much how it looks.

Comment: I noticed also that with navbar-fixed-top the nav covers my example text, so it's not the solution i'm searching.